# Left hand and right hand derivatives of $x\sin ({1\over x})$ at $0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, proof-verification

> If $$f(x)= \begin{cases} 
> x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & x\neq 0
> \\0 & x=0 
> \end{cases}$$ 
>   Then
>
> $A.$ $f$ is continuous.
>
> $B.$ $f'(0+)$  exists  but  $f'(0-)$  does not.
>
> $C.$  $f'(0+)\neq f'(0-)$
>
> $D.$  $f'(0+)$ and $f'(0-)$ do not exist .

$A.$ is true that is trivial . Now $$f'(0+)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} {{f(0+h)-f(0)}\over h}\\=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}{{h\sin{1\over h}}\over h}\\=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\  \sin{1\over h}$$ and similarly $$f'(0-)=-\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\sin{1\over h}$$  Both these limits do not exist , am I right $?$ Then it should be $D.$ is also true  not just $A.$ or did I make any mistake $?$

Comment: The function $f$ is even function [$f(x)=f(-x)$], so what is problem in (B)?

Comment: @pGroups : Huh $?$

Comment: For an even function, the existence of $f'(0^+)$ implies the existence of $f'(0^-)$ and they are equal.

Comment: Your argument is correct @user118494 (assuming you can prove $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \sin(1/h)$ does not exist.

Comment: notice also that, if $D$ is true, then also $A$ is true. Viceversa, if $A$ is true, it is not necessary that $D$ is also true.

Comment: @the_candyman The derivative of an even function is an odd function and is usually not even.